# Android Network Status with Job Scheduling

Tags: android, job-scheduling

I have used broadcast receiver to check network connection, but with android 7.0 it's not allowed any more. So, I want to handle this problem with Job Scheduling, but I do not know how to do it. Is there any good resource about Job Scheduling or piece of code that check network status with Job Scheduling.

Comment: checkout this link https://github.com/firebase/firebase-jobdispatcher-android
might be helpful fro you

Comment: check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39880860/5846135

Comment: thank u for responses.

Answer (score 1):

Frameworks, like Android JobScheduler or Firebase Jobdispatcher provide a feature that allow you to define constraints when a job should be executed. One constraint might be that network has to be available.

There are some implementations for Job scheduling on Android, like Android Jobscheduler or Firebase Jobdispatcher. [This gives you an overview](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/scheduling.html)

If you use Firebase Jobdispatcher, you can define that you Job should only be executed if network is available, like this:

```
Job myJob = dispatcher.newJobBuilder()
  // the JobService that will be called
  .setService(MyJobService.class)
  // uniquely identifies the job
  .setTag("my-unique-tag")
  // constraints that need to be satisfied for the job to run
  .setConstraints(
    // only run if any network is available
    Constraint.ON_ANY_NETWORK
  )
.build();

dispatcher.mustSchedule(myJob);
```

Source: [Firebase Jobdispatcher](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-jobdispatcher-android/tree/master/jobdispatcher/src/main/java/com/firebase/jobdispatcher)

Comment: thank you for your response, I'll look them, but I'm looking for more completed samples.